# How to detect whether the Crystal Report was actually printed

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am looking for a method to detect whether the crystal report was actually printed after my code instructs that a printout is required.

For example, if the program sends out the print command & the printer happened to be turned off or disconnected then how can I detect that a pint out was not actually taken.

I used the below VB.Net code for direct crystal report printing without a preview.

```
Dim myReport as New ReportDocument()
myReport.Load("C:\mylocation\myReport.rpt")
'//database & param info here
myReport.PrinttoPrinter(1,true,0,0)
```

Comment: but you can check whether a printer is `ON/OFF` using `vb.net`, right ??

Comment: check this http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/65798/Get-printer-status-after-pdf-file-is-printed